# using abortBroadcast() in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android

how can in use abortBroadcast() function in BroadcastReceiver when TelephonyManager is equals to `CALL_STATE_RINGING`?

Answer (score 0):

Have your class extend `extends PhoneStateListener`

Override onCallStageChanged()

```
@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
         // phone is ringing, do your thing with abortBroadcast()
    }
}
```

and implement your abort as you see fit

---

If you get `BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast`, remove the call to `setResultCode();`